# Preloaded media query CSS doesn't applies on resize in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive, preload

I've tried to use rel="preload" on my CSS links with media attribute.

And everything working fine, except in Chrome the media query rules doesn't apply on window resize.

Here is the links:

```
<link  href="${URLUtils.staticURL('/css/main.css')}" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" type="text/css" rel="preload">
<link  href="${URLUtils.staticURL('/css/responsive-767px-max.css')}" as="style" media="screen and (max-width: 767px)" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" type="text/css" rel="preload">
<link  href="${URLUtils.staticURL('/css/responsive-768px-979px.css')}" as="style" media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" type="text/css" rel="preload">
<link  href="${URLUtils.staticURL('/css/responsive-980px-1199px.css')}" as="style" media="screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px)" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" type="text/css" rel="preload">
<link  href="${URLUtils.staticURL('/css/responsive-1200px-min.css')}" as="style" media="screen and (min-width: 1200px)" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" type="text/css" rel="preload">
```

I've tested it in Safari and Mozile, and the media query rules on resize works just fine. And it works in Chrome without rel="preload".

Is it known issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a browser issue. Can you please file a bug at https://crbug.com and post the bug link here? I could then take a look at the issue